# React.useState is changing initialValues const

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm experiencing some odd behavior with react's `useState` hook. I would like to know why this is happening. I can see a few ways to sidestep this behavior, but want to know whats going on.

I am initializing the state with the following const:

```
const initialValues = {
  order_id: '',
  postal_code: '',
  products: [
    {
      number: '',
      qty: ''
    }
  ]
}

const App = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState(initialValues);
...
```

`products` is an array of variable size. As the user fills in fields more appear.
The change handler is:

```
  const handleProductChange = (key) => (field) => (e) => {
    if (e.target.value >= 0 || e.target.value == '') {
      let products = values.products;
      products[key][field] = e.target.value;
      setValues({ ...values, products });
    }
  }
```

What I am noticing is that if I console log `initialValues`, the products change when the fields are changed. None of the other fields change, only inside the array.

[Here is a codepen of a working example](https://codepen.io/briant1414/pen/ExxVmmX?editors=0011).

How is this possible? If you look at the full codepen, you'll see that `initialValues` is only referenced when setting default state, and resetting it. So I don't understand why it would be trying to update that variable at all. In addition, its a `const` declared outside of the component, so shouldn't that not work anyway?

I attempted the following with the same result:

```
const initialProducts = [
  {
    number: '',
    qty: ''
  }
];

const initialValues = {
  order_id: '',
  postal_code: '',
  products: initialProducts
}
```

In this case, both consts were modified.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: use multiple `useState` and avoid using nested object and array inside them which is resulting in your issue. Its because you are trying to modify things and then spread out `...values` but that spread contains pointer to the OLD ref which happens to be initial value. By doing `products.push({number: '', qty: ''});` you are modifying Initial value

Comment: `products[key][field] = e.target.value` is the problem. You're modifying the properties within the `const` reference, rather than creating a new reference to replace the initial value.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I see that that is whats happening, but why does `let products = values.products;` not fix that? Shouldn't that make it so that only the new variable is being modified?

Comment: @BrianThompson variables are just references. An assignment doesn't copy an object, it just causes the left-hand side to reference the evaluated expression on the right hand side.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation

Comment: Also [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is not to be confused with [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). `const foo = { key: 'value' };` prevents `foo = { key: 'new value' };` but it doesn't prevent `foo.key = 'new value';`, whereas `let foo = Object.freeze({ key: 'value' });` prevents the latter but not the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest move forward is to create a new `useState` for `products` which I had started to suspect before asking the question, but a solution to keep the logic similar to how it was before would be:

```js
let products = values.products.map(product => ({...product}));
```

to create a completely new array as well as new nested objects.

As @PatrickRoberts pointed out, the `products` variable was not correctly creating a new array, but was continuing to point to the array reference in state, which is why it was being modified.

More explanation on the underlying reason `initialValues` was changed: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 1):

Alongside exploding state into multiple of 1 level deep you may inline your initial:

```
  = useState({ ... });
```

or wrap it into function

```
function getInitial() {
  return {
  ....
  };
}

// ...

 = useState(getInitial());
```

Both approaches will give you brand new object on each call so you will be safe.

Anyway you are responsible to decide if you need 2+ level nested state. Say I see it legit to have someone's information to be object with `address` been object as well(2nd level deep). Splitting state into `targetPersonAddress`, `sourePersonAddress` and `whoEverElsePersonAddress` just to avoid nesting looks like affecting readability to me.

Comment: I would agree with the comment on readability. And I like the idea of making initial values a function that returns the object, and I may still use that. However, this will only stop the `initialValues` from being modified, the state object's nested values are still mutable, and were being mutated the way it was written. I didn't want to inline the initial state to make it easy and clear when resetting the form to just set values back to initial.

Comment: yeah, it addresses only part of issue you've run into, I saw rest was discussed in comments in details.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good candidate for a custom hook. Let's call it `usePureState()` and allow it to be used the same as `useState()` except the dispatcher can accept nested objects which will immutably update the state. To implement it, we'll use [`useReducer()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead of `useState()`:

```
const pureReduce = (oldState, newState) => (
  oldState instanceof Object
    ? Object.assign(
        Array.isArray(oldState) ? [...oldState] : { ...oldState },
        ...Object.keys(newState).map(
          key => ({ [key]: pureReduce(oldState[key], newState[key]) })
        )
      )
    : newState
);

const usePureState = initialState => (
  React.useReducer(pureReduce, initialState)
);
```

Then the usage would be:

```
const [values, setValues] = usePureState(initialValues);
...
const handleProductChange = key => field => event => {
  if (event.target.value >= 0 || event.target.value === '') {
    setValues({
      products: { [key]: { [field]: event.target.value } }
    });
  }
};
```